# JSON or XML with single element not coming as array problem solution through Jolt Transform?

Tags: java, arrays, json, xml, jolt

Problem Statement :

While mapping XML or Json through Jackson or other Java libraries then arrays are incorrectly serialized in certain cases. i.e

When an array has more than 1 entry, it is serialized correctly

```
{
  "Car": {
    "data": [
      {
        "car": "Toyota"
      },
      {
        "car": "Maruti"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but when the array has only 1 entry, it is serialized not as an array, but as a single object.

```
{
  "Car": {
    "data": {
      "car": "Maruti"
    }
  }
}
```

Solution through Jolt Transform?

Comment: Can you please share a minimal, reproducible example along with an input, tried spec and expected output ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution for this problem through JOLT :

INPUT 1 :

```
{
  "Car": {
    "data": [
      {
        "car": "Toyota"
      },
      {
        "car": "Maruti"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

INPUT 2:

```
{
  "Car": {
    "data": [
      {
        "car": "Toyota"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

JOLT SPEC :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "Car": {
        "data": "MANY"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: the `input 2` here is different from the one within the question, which one should be the input?